# Trouble with posting data to database using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have looked up tutorials multiple times and am having trouble figuring out where my code is wrong. I am able to run my php file and get my information sent into my database, so I know my connection isn't the issue, so I am thinking its my index.html file. It may have something to do with how i tried to implement jquery, but I don't know about that either

Index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#login').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
          var username =$('#use').val();
          var pass = $('#pass').val();
  
          $.ajax({
              url: 'login.php',
              method:'POST',
              data:
              {
                  User: username,
                  Pass: pass
              },
              success:function(result){
                  alert(result);
              }
          });
      });
  });</script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login-page">
        <div class="form">
          <form class="register-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
            <button>create</button>
            <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
          </form>
          <form class="login-form">
            <input type="text" id="use" placeholder="username"/>
            <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="password"/>
            <button type="submit" id="login">login</button>
            <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code connecting to my DB

```
<?php
$dbname = 'project test';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbhost = 'localhost';

$username=$_POST['use'];
$password=$_POST['pass'];

$conn= mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (User, Pass)
    VALUES ('{$username}','{$password}')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close(); ;

?>
```

Comment: There is typo in your code you have pass `User` and `Pass` in your ajax and you are getting it using `$_POST['use']` , `$_POST['pass']` ..etc i.e: `User != use` and same for other .

Comment: Wide open SQL injections possible with your code, do NOT use in production.

Comment: This is just for a test. I can't even get form data yet, so haven't been able to even factor in security.

Comment: Use built-in PDO https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your index.html file, you are sending `User` and `Password` values However, when you are trying to get them in your php file, you are trying to get `use` and `pass` values. Their names don't match. The names need to match in order to get the values correctly.

Comment: So I have matched the php files with what is within my ajax file, but still nothing is happening on the button click.